# Is it necessary to ask for permissions on Android 6+?

Tags: android

After all the hassle of searching on google, I have managed to request storage permission, to make my apps "compliant" with the new permission system introduced in android [Marshmallow](https://www.android.com/versions/marshmallow-6-0/). But now, I noticed, I actually didn't need to make all that effort as permissions get granted by the system automatically without requesting. Just having the permissions in Manifest was enough.(seen while installing ES File Explorer, or my own apps). Is it necessary to ask for permissions on Android 6+?

This is what my Manifest.xml looks like:

```
android:versionCode="100"
android:versionName="1.0.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

PS: I am using a Samsung Galaxy S7

Comment: No they do not get granted automatically. Please deinstall app first to see.

Comment: @greenapps okay, so I deinstalled the app, tried installing it from Eclipse and also from the backup I created on SD card. Both approaches seemed to have the same results. Permissions were being granted automatically.

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: i don't have a targetSDKversion specified

Comment: @CommonsWare when targetSDK isn't set, doesn't it automatically set itself to the newest API?(as of now, 25)

Comment: @joey do you have anything defined in your gradle-file?

Comment: If `targetSdkVersion` is not set in either the manifest or Gradle, it defaults to 1.

Comment: @CommonsWare so this can be a hack for getting permission without requesting?

Comment: @joey: This is covered in LunarWatcher's answer. If your `targetSdkVersion` is below 23, you do not need to request permissions at runtime. However, you seem to think that this "hack" is a good thing. Users may disagree.

Comment: @joey consider all of the unupdated apps after a new API comes and hits the market. There are still several (a lot of apps, I do not have a figure on it) that target API 22 and below and they request permissions on install, not runtime. WHen runnning on API 23, the permissions that are dangerous can be revoked at any time, meaning apps targeting API 22 and below will not be able to check if the app has the permissions **and then** __request them__.  If your target SDK is currently 1, that can cause other problems. So if you want to request permissions, set the target SDK to 23. If not, 22.

Comment: Either way you should set the TargetSDK to something, because setting it to 1(default when not specified) can cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

> Do we actually need to request permissions?

No. If you set target API to 22 or below(ANdroid 5.x) the permission system isn't set up and thus, when downloading the app the user has to grant every permission to download the app.

## HOWEVER

The user can still revoke **any** permission on the "dangerous"-level. If your app uses any of these, you can't ask for them back either. In addition, it will cause crashes as the app will not be programmed to handle what happens when the app doesn't have access to the permissions.

You only need to ask for permission on the permissions that have the danger-level of "Dangerous". "normal"-permissions are granted automatically and can not be revoked. [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#perm-groups) is a list of the dangerous permissions that you need to ask for.

Considering:

- Revoking
- User security(and privacy conserns from users who really care about this)

it is best to ask for permissions. This will also prevent crashes when permissions are revoked. even targeting API 22 and below, the permissions can still be revoked and cause problems where ever you call something that require these permissions.

Only when targeting API 23, and requesting permissions, can you control your app. You can ask for permissions where you need them, and without access you can block features and also let the user know what the permission is being used for, and giving the user the feeling that the permission isn't being used for something malicious or privacy-violating.

---

As mentioned in [this answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42539812/6296561):

> Yes, We need to request permission from user. Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

It is not a requirement, but if you target API 22(Android 5) the permissions are still asked for when the app is installed. A lot of apps would not be allowed to install if apps that targeted API 22 were "incompatible" with ANdroid 6.

> If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.

Apps targeting Android 5.x and lower will still install the same way on Android 6: You cannot allow or disallow single permissions on install if the app targets API 22. Permissions can be revoked from settings, but no permissions can be blocked from install when it is targeting API 22.

---

In ANdroid Manifest, you still have to list all your permissions, both normal and dangerous. If the app targets API 23, it will require all the permissions on Android 5.x and lower, and request on API 23 and up(remember to check if the user is on API 23 or up before requesting).

To summarize:

Requesting is not a requirement. It is, however, a good idea to do so and make sure you design the app to only do what it has permission to. Thus: You do not have to request permissions, but it is a very good idea to do it.

When targeting API 23, no permissions are granted automatically. You have to ask for them. When targeting API 22, the permissions are automatically granted and consented to when the user installs the app.

**Also note:**

Android is progressing fast. Android 7(API 24 &25) also use the permission system. In a few years, all Android-devices may run on the permission system, at which point it is a good idea to already have integrated the permission-system into your app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, We need to request permission from user.
Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

System permissions are divided into two categories, normal and dangerous:

Normal permissions do not directly risk the user's privacy. If your app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the permission automatically.

Dangerous permissions can give the app access to the user's confidential data. If your app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the permission automatically. If you list a dangerous permission, the user has to explicitly give approval to your app.

However, the effect of that declaration is different depending on the system version and your app's target SDK level:

If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.

If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.